# Student t distribution: standardization

Tags: distributions, density-function, standardization, t-distribution

I got a question concerning the standardization of a student t distribution.
I see that the "plain vanilla" t distribution has density $f(x|\nu)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2}) }{\sqrt{\pi\nu}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})}\bigg(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu}\bigg)^{\frac{-(v+1)}{2}}
$ with $\nu$ being the df parameter. This distribution has a variance of $\nu/(\nu-2)$, iff $\nu>2$.

If my data has e.g. $\nu = 6$ it follows that the variance of it is equal 1.5.
If I want to standardize it, I have to transform the data like $z= \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$.

What I don't know is how this works if I want to apply the transformation to the density function?

I found the following definition:
$f(x|\mu,\sigma^2,\nu) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu + 1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi (\nu - 2)}}  \frac{1}{\sigma} \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{\nu - 2} \left( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 \bigg)^{-\frac{\nu + 1}{2}}$,

where $\sigma^2$ is the variance and $\mu$ is the mean.

But I don't know how the transition from the first equation to the second works. Why is there an adjustment of $\nu - 2$? 
I've read a lot of text books but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer. 
I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please tell us what $\sigma$ is intended to mean in the definition you found.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I edited my question. Btw, the source is Lambert/Laurent (2002).

Comment: OK, so that means the original variance of $\nu/(\nu-2)$ has to be multiplied by $\sigma^2(\nu-2)/\nu$ in order to create a variance of $\sigma^2$. That's done by rescaling $x$ by the square root of that quantity; the rest is pure algebra.  I have re-directed this thread to another that explains and illustrates the concepts.